# How can I make this regex match correctly?

Tags: regex

I'm writing a lexical parser/analyzer which analyzes the specified text according to a set of predefined regular expressions and I'm having a bit of trouble:

Let's say we want to analyze a text with N amount of parts, like this

```
A, B, C[, N]
```

Now, I want every matched part to be accessible within the regular expression itself, so I can access the previous matched parts with

```
$X
```

My solution was to use (ignoring any implicit whitespace or line-breaks)

```
([A-Za-z]*)                         //A
(?:\s|\n)*                          //Whitespace
((?:,) (?:\s|\n)* ([A-Za-z]* ))*    //, B etc.
```

The result I want, is the following:

```
1. A
2. B
3. C
```

but the result I'm getting is.. less than desirable:

```
1. A
2. , C
3. C
```

Why is this, and how can I improve it to match my text correctly?

Comment: If you mean "do that to match a string": I don't need a tutorial on how to import some regex library and then match against a string.

Comment: If you're actually curious: I haven't decided, though I'll probably
write a first draft in C# or C++ (I love the syntax of both :P), but I know I'll sooner or late want to write it in either C or Lisp.

Comment: I don't want to give you a tutorial in importing a lib. In fact, regular expressions are language dependent, for that, its written in the tag description " ...  include a tag specifying the programming language ...". Especially when it comes to how to access the match results, then its definitely not portable. As Tim wrote in his answer, it would be possible to access such repeated capturing groups in .net, but thats the only language I know, where this is possible, so he gave you a Python solution, but I am sure for C or C++ or Lisp it will look differently.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard some about how it differ across implementations, but I've never heard anything about the actual differences. [See comment on KayKay's answer]: I've always thought the differences as minor details, not major concepts/functionality.

Comment: You can find [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) a flavour comparison. Thats only on the pure regex syntax/features of the different languages. But how you call a regex, set the modifiers or access the results is really completely language dependent and I think your problem is mainly on how to access the result and less on the regex itself.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the link! Anyhow, why do you think it is about that, rather than about the regex? In my experience, problems on how to manipulate and/or access the state of different objects are rather minor, and really only a matter of understanding the syntax of the language and/or the framework you're using.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're repeating your capturing group, overwriting each match result with the next until the final one (so in your case `, B` is overwritten by `, C`).

This is just how regexes work; some implementations like .NET allow you to access all individual captures of a repeated group, but most don't.

So better iterate over your matches. If you really want to keep the delimiters (why?), you can do it like this:

```
(?:\s*,\s*)?[A-Za-z]+
```

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "A, B, C, D"
>>> r = re.compile(r"(?:\s*,\s*)?[A-Za-z]+")
>>> r.findall(a)
['A', ', B', ', C', ', D']
```

Side note: `\s` already includes `\n`, so `(?:\s|\n)*` is redundant - `\s*` will do.

Answer (score 1):

This row:

```
((?:,) (?:\s|\n)* ([A-Za-z]* ))*    //, B etc.
```

make it this way:

```
(?:(?:,) (?:\s|\n)* ([A-Za-z]* ))*    //, B etc.
```

This happen because your original Regex "created" 2 captures:

- the external `()` (that included both the internal capturing and non-capturing groups)
- the internal `([A-Za-z]* )` capturing group

Answer (score 1):

Make the biggest group non-capturing :

```
(?:, (?:\s|\n)* ([A-Za-z]*))*
```

I also simplified `(?:,)` to just `,`.

Comment: Wouldn't this hide the smaller groups, e.g B and C in (A(B(C)?

Comment: No, at least in java. What language are you using?

Comment: [See my comment on question]: I know the various dialects of regex differ somewhat between implementations, but I thought the differences where "minor" (e.g basic things like handling of grouping remain, but things like lookahead/assertions and/or active grouping might differ)?

Answer (score 1):

Would capturing just the `[A-Za-z]+` groups work out for you?

```
  public static void main(String[] foo) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)(?:, )?");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("A, B, C, D");
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }

  }
```

outputs :

```
A
B
C
D
```

Is that enough?

Comment: Thing is, it isn't certain the delimiter will be in the text. To express the purpose of the regex in pseudo-code: IF delimiter THEN multiple ELSE singel, e.g IF ([A-Za-z],) THEN identify_each_w/o_delimiter ELSE [A-Za-z]*